# Problema al iniciar un proyecto en React desde MAC

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, terminal, macos

Al hacer correr, desde el terminal en MAC, un proyecto en React, me envía el siguiente mensaje:

> error: Can't find the 'node' binary to build the React Native bundle.
>   If you have a non-standard Node.js installation, select your project
>   in Xcode, find  'Build Phases' - 'Bundle React Native code and images'
>   and change NODE_BINARY to an  absolute path to your node executable.
>   You can find it by invoking 'which node' in the terminal.

Después de esto el simulador se me queda con una pantalla negra. Agradecería vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que si ejecutas la siguiente linea en el terminal (sin el %)

```
% which node
```

El `node` no está ubicado en la ruta `/usr/local/bin/node`

En este [post (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492197/react-native-ios-build-cant-find-node) recomiendan crear un `symlink` a `node` lo cual es mucho más sencillo.

Escribe esto en tu terminal (sin el %):

```
% ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Si vuelves a ejecutar la sentencia anterior debería imprimirse `ln: /usr/local/bin/node: File exists` o simplemente ejecutando `which node` se imprimirá `/usr/local/bin/node`